# I want to get part of a data from a postgresql database as a json object

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, oop

I have a postgres database where I am fetching data from. However I am merging data from 2 tables and I want the data from the other table to be returned as a Json object named vehicle details. I will appreciate if you can kindly correct where I am getting the json_build_object wrong. I am not clear on how json_build_object works for now

THe query is as below

```
SELECT      vr.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
        mechanic_signature, supervisor_signature
        FROM vr 
        LEFT JOIN users ON vr.inspector_id=users.id 
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id,
        json_build_object( 
        'id', veh.id,
        'make', veh.make,
        ) AS vd
        FROM vehicles v
        ) vr
        ON vr.vehicle_id = v.id
        WHERE vr.id=1
        GROUP BY  vr.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
        mechanic_signature, supervisor_signature
```

Answer (score 0):

The form for json_build_object is correct:

```
select json_build_object('cell_per', cell_per, 'category', category) from cell_per;
              json_build_object               
----------------------------------------------
 {"cell_per" : 18, "category" : "HERB 3.5"}
 {"cell_per" : 18, "category" : "H PREM 3.5"}
 {"cell_per" : 1, "category" : "HERB G"}
 {"cell_per" : 1, "category" : "HERB TOP"}
```

What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I was able to figure it out